# Update SQL command for inventory system

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I develop an inventory system, in sale form we have an datagridview that we fill the items then "settle" button to cut the items from inventory. But my code sometimes doesn't work and our inventory items are not the same as we cut with SQL command.

For example: I have 20 Mobile when I cut 3 it left 7 or 5. I think my command is not much read-able.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    mycon.Open();
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Data1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity= Quantity - " + Data1.Rows[y].Cells[2].Value + " where ItemName='" + Data1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value + "'", mycon);
        cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        y += 1;
    }

    mycon.Close();
}
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erorr404");
        }
```

With Parameters code:

```
mycon.Open();
                int y = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    string sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[Pharmacy_Items] Set Quantity= Quantity - @Quantity where ItemName=@ItemName";

                    using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(sql, mycon))
                    {
                        cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        var qunatityParam = new SqlParameter { Value = dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[2].Value, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "Quantity" };
                        var itemNameParam = new SqlParameter { Value = dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterName = "ItemName" };

                        cmd5.Parameters.Add(qunatityParam);
                        cmd5.Parameters.Add(itemNameParam);
                        cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    y += 1;
                }
                mycon.Close();
```

Comment: With is displayed in the gridview? It might be that the same item is displayed multiple times. Therefor when you run the command it updates it multiple times.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection. You should create **one** `SqlCommand` **with parameters** before the `for` loop, and then inside the loop only set the **values** of the parameters, to execute the command

Comment: @SQLInjectionalert i add sql command with parameters please take a look ( :

Comment: What you mean by `Quantity= Quantity-`???

Comment: @RameshRajendran I want to decrease Quantity from database